# LINQ - GroupBy a key and then put each grouped item into separate 'buckets'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-group

I have a list of items as such:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int ListId { get; set; }
}
```

`1 Test1 1`

`2 Test2 1`

`3 Test3 1`

`4 List 2`

`5 List2 2`

`6 Testing 3`

`7 Testing2 3`

`8 Testing3 3`

Is there a way for me to group by the `ListId` and put them into each separate buckets, i.e, `ListId1` bucket will have all items with `ListId == 1`. The list is dynamically returned from SQL, so I don't know before hand how many `ListId` there will be.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534492.aspx):

```
var groups = items.GroupBy(item => item.ListId);

foreach(var group in groups)
{
     Console.WriteLine("List with ID == {0}", group.Key);
     foreach(var item in group)
        Console.WriteLine("    Item: {0}", item.ItemName);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Let's create your list of items:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 1, ItemName = "Test1", ListId = 1 });
items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 2, ItemName = "Test2", ListId = 1 });
items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 3, ItemName = "Test3", ListId = 1 });
items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 4, ItemName = "List", ListId = 2 });
items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 5, ItemName = "List2", ListId = 2 });
items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 6, ItemName = "Testing", ListId = 3 });
items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 7, ItemName = "Testing2", ListId = 3 });
items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 8, ItemName = "Testing3", ListId = 3 });

var groupByResult = items.GroupBy(i => i.ListId);
```

After this `GroupBy` call, `groupByResult` is a variable of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Item>>` which is basically a collection of objects that implement [`IGrouping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) interface. This allows you to iterate through all items as `IGrouping` is derived from `IEnumerable<>` and has an extra field named `Key`:

```
public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable
{
    TKey Key { get; }
}
```

Briefly said, a `GroupBy` method call returns **a list of lists**. An outer list corresponds to 'buckets' as you mentioned in your question. Then each 'bucket' contains items corresponding to that 'bucket'. To be specific to your example, the value of `groupByResult` is depicted in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BpfQ.png) screenshot. As we can see there, your initial collection was grouped into three different buckets that have 3, 2 and 3 items, respectively.

As for accessing items in these groups, you can use simple LINQ:

```
List<Item> firstBucketItems = groupByResult.First(i => i.Key == 1).ToList();
List<Item> secondBucketItems = groupByResult.First(i => i.Key == 2).ToList();
List<Item> thirdBucketItems = groupByResult.First(i => i.Key == 3).ToList();
```

[image: First bucket items]

Or you can just iterate through all items:

```
foreach (var itemGroup in groupByResult)
{
    int groupKey = itemGroup.Key;

    foreach (Item item in itemGroup)
    {
        // Do whatever...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>()
    { 
    new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 21 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 18 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Abram" , Age = 21 } 
    };
```

`var groupedResult = from s in studentList group s by s.Age;`

//iterate each group

```
foreach (var ageGroup in groupedResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Age Group: {0}", ageGroup.Key); //Each group has a key 

    foreach(Student s in ageGroup) // Each group has inner collection
        Console.WriteLine("Student Name: {0}", s.StudentName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic format

```
  var res = (from i in items
                           group i by i.ListId into g
                           select  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 1, ItemName = "Test1", ListId = 1 });
        items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 2, ItemName = "Test2", ListId = 1 });
        items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 3, ItemName = "Test3", ListId = 1 });
        items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 4, ItemName = "List", ListId = 2 });
        items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 5, ItemName = "List2", ListId = 2 });
        items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 6, ItemName = "Testing", ListId = 3 });
        items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 7, ItemName = "Testing2", ListId = 3 });
        items.Add(new Item() { ItemId = 8, ItemName = "Testing3", ListId = 3 });

        var groupByResult = items.GroupBy(i => i.ListId);
        List<GroupedItems> betterGroups = new List<GroupedItems>();
        foreach (var groupedItem in groupByResult)
        {
            betterGroups.Add(new GroupedItems() { ListId = groupedItem.Key, Items = groupedItem.ToList() });
            // ListId = 1 , List<Item> 3 records 
            // ListId = 2 , List<Item> 2 records
            // ListId = 3 , List<Item> 3 records
            // You can iteratre throught ListId
        }
    }
    
    public class Item
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int ListId { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class GroupedItems
    {
        public int ListId {get; set;}
        public List<Item> Items {get; set;}
    }
}
```

donetFiddle example [Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DFijrh)